# UnicodeDecodeError: charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 756

Tags: python-3.x

I'm unable to retrieve the data from a Microsoft Excel document. I've tried using encoding 'Latin-1' or 'UTF-8' but when it gives me hundreds of \x00's in the terminal. Is there any way I can retrieve the data and output it to a text file?

**This is what I'm running on the terminal and the error I get:**

PS C:\Users\Andy-\Desktop> python.exe SRT411-Lab2.py Lab2Data.xlsx

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SRT411-Lab2.py", line 9, in 
    lines = file.readlines()
  File "C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 756: character maps to <\undefined>

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

    import sys  

    filename = sys.argv[1]
    print(filename)
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    print(lines)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably convert the excel file to csv file and use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) to parse it

Comment: Thanks, I figured out how to convert to csv, then parsed the data and it worked!